# Checking out an SVN and skip files with invalid filenames on Windows

Tags: windows-7, subversion

I am looking for a program that:

- can check out an SVN repository and, [unlike TortoiseSVN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27879179/395857), can skip files that are considered having an invalid filenames
- works on Windows 7

I don't mind about the price.

Comment: The problem is that skipping files that do not have valid file names in Windows means that your repository then not complete on that platform IIRC the recommended solution is to have a project rule about valid file names being ASCII, and something matching the pattern [A-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_-+.]{0-125} and to have a pre-commit filter that stops users from creating files that don't match the rule.